# Drop rows in a subset of columns in mixed data type data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to drop values that are not equal to `1` or `0` across several columns but not including some columns

this is what I started with

```
df=pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df.head()
     Age  Prod1  Prod2  Day 4  Day 5 ...  Region
0    18     1      0      1.0    5.0  0     1
1    89     3      1      1.0    1.0  1     1
2    100    4      7      0.0    1.0  1     0
3    200    0      1      0.0    0.0  1     0
4    300    1      1      0.0    1.0  1     1
5    19     1      1      1.0    1.0  6     1
```

there are a total of 10,000 rows and 34 columns

the first two columns I have cleaned successfully because they have numeric values that are different from the rest.

Here is what I did

```
ageindex = df[ (df['Age'] < 18) & (dfl['Age'] > 150) ].index
df.drop(ageindex)
```

I want to drop the rows from columns `Prod1` through the end `Region`. It is only 34 columns but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

I have found a way to drop NaN values here but not how to drop using conditions based on values.

Here is what I have tried

```
prodindex1 = df[ (df.loc['Prod1':'Region'] > 1) ].index
df.drop(prodindex1)
```

but that just returns the same dataframe. I also tried

```
prodindex = df[ (df.loc['Prod1':'Region'] > 1) & (df.loc['Prod1':'Region'] < 0) ].index
df.drop(prodindex)
```

The Expected output should be

```
     Age  Prod1  Prod2  Day 4  Day 5 ...  Region
3    200    0      1      0.0    0.0  1     0
4    300    1      1      0.0    1.0  1     1
```

I think I have some problems because some of them are whole numbers and some are floats. Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT: i want to drop where values are not equal to or not equal to 0

Comment: Do you delete rows whose columns (between Prod1..Region) are not equal to 1 and 0, or those which are between 0 and 1?

Comment: Not equal to 1 or 0 ill edit to make more clear

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# Sample data
d = np.array([[18, 1, 0, 1.0, 5.0, 0, 1],
                [89, 3, 1, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1],
                [100, 4, 7, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0],
                [200, 0, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 1, 0],
                [300, 1, 1, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 1],
                [19, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, 6, 1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns = ['Age','Prod1','Prod2', 'Day 4', 'Day 5', 'Day 6', 'Region'])
df = df.drop(df[~df.loc[:, 'Prod1':'Region'].isin([0, 1]).all(axis=1)].index)    
print(df)
```

should give the expected output:

```
     Age  Prod1  Prod2  Day 4  Day 5  Day 6  Region
3  200.0    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    1.0     0.0
4  300.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    1.0    1.0     1.0
```

**Comment on your code:** 
Your conditions are wrong but this is not the reason why you are getting the same dataframe. This happens because you are not passing `df.drop(prodindex)` to a variable, i.e:

```
# Your code
prodindex = df[ (df.loc['Prod1':'Region'] > 1) & (df.loc['Prod1':'Region'] < 0) ].index
df = df.drop(prodindex)
print(df) 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Age, Prod1, Prod2, Day 4, Day 5, Day 6, Region]
Index: []
```

Comment: If i use this I get "'DataFrame' object is not callable" error

Comment: Works fine for me. I updated my answer in order to include the full script.

Comment: Ok that dropped rows but it dropped all rows. I started with a csv file that has 34 columns. Do I need to specify a dataframe and type out all the column names for all 34 columns?

Comment: If this hasn’t worked as expected then you have desribed your problem or dataset incorrectly.

Comment: I added more details I am not sure what I am missing. I started with a csv file if that makes a difference. Do i need to explicitly name all 34 column names like in your example? I started with just df=pd.read_csv('df.csv')

Comment: i'm starting with a csv file not explicitly creating an np.array. is this a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference as far as the resulting dataframe is the same. The dataframe I created is exactly the same to the one provided.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df[df.loc[:, 'Prod1':'Region'].isin([0, 1]).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: There is at least one row that does not drop when I use this. The row has a value equal to 1 0 and it is still present.

Comment: @aardvark I cannot reproduce that. When run on your provided data, only rows 3 and 4 are left, as stated in the question.

Comment: Weird. I am missing something in this so I'm sorry. I have to assume your solution works and it is on my end that I am messing up. thanks

Comment: @aardvark do you mean that it doesn't work on your full dataset? Could you provide more details please?

Comment: Yes on the full data set this is not working. It does not drop one row where Day6=10 I added details to the original post. I started with a csv file. I know how to go through each column individually and drop the values just not how to do it quicker. I have removed NaN values and dropped values using the Age column before this step.

Comment: @aardvark I honestly can't reproduce that behaviour still...could you provide a sample of the exact data where you face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove rows containing values 1 or 0, following works:

`df.loc[~df.loc[:, 'Prod1':'Region'].isin([0, 1]).any(axis=1), :]`